# Add shortcuts for duplicated menu items in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I use the following  path to locate the first "Update Frames" (Selected Views), and successfully change its default keybaord shortcut to "comand + alt + -"

```
Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Update Frames
```

But I don't know how to locate the second "Update Frames" (All Views), thank you!

OS X 10.9.5, Xcode 6.2

The screenshot of Xcode Menu has been pasted in the link
[Xcode Menu](https://justpaste.it/k7sd)

Answer (score 1):

How are you modifying the keyboard shortcut? I suspect you're using System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. Don't do that.

Go into Xcode's Preferences. Select the Key Bindings tab. In the search field above the list of bindings, type "update frames". There will be two items listed, one for each Update Frames menu item. You can change the shortcut for each independently there. Double-click on the cell in the Key column for the desired row (menu item). Just type the new key combination to change it.